# Rails and bootstrap - can't get rows with3 divs each to align properly

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to get my site to show 3 article divs in each row using bootstrap 3 grid system:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<h1>NEWS</h1>

  <div class="row">

      <% @articles.each do |article| %>

        <div class="col-sm-4">
          <h2><%= article.title %></h2> 
          <p><strong>Author: </strong>
            <% article.author_id do |c| %>
              <p><%= c.first_name %></p>
            <% end %></p> 
          <p><strong>Excerpt: </strong><%= article.excerpt %></p> 

          <p><strong>Category: </strong>
            <% article.categories.each do |c| %>
              <%= c.name %>
            <% end %>
          </p> 

          <p><strong>Nr of comments: </strong><%= article.comments.count %></p> 

            <%= link_to article do %>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Show
              </button>
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to edit_article_path(article) do %>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Edit
              </button>
            <% end %>
            <%= link_to article, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }  do %>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete
              </button>
            <% end %>

        </div>
    <% end %>

          </div> <!-- .row -->

    </div> <!-- .container -->
<% content_for :aside do %>
  <%= render 'sidebar_popular' %>
  <%= render 'sidebar_categories' %>
<% end %>
```

The first row is perfect but second renders only two divs (as in the picture)
http://postimg.org/image/c5uwv6iyn/

How can I fix that? I tried inserting  but that didnt change anything (maybe i put it in the wrong place).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the looks of it you are rendering all of the columns in a single row. You need to change the   `<% @articles.each do |article| %>`
so that it starts a new row every three columns i.e.

```
  <% @articles.each_slice(3).to_a.each do |chunk| %>
     <div class="row">
       <% chunk.each do |article| %>
         <div class="col-sm-4">
           ...
         </div>
       <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

You might not need the to_a on the first loop